# Why is the area from $1$ to $2$ of $\frac{1}{x}$ the same as the area from $6$ to $12$?

Tags: calculus

I get this in the calculus sense- you integrate and $\ln \frac{2}{1}$ and $\ln \frac{12}{6}$ are the same, but how would I answer this with a non-calculus answer? Why do they have the same area?

Comment: Not in a rigorous way: the transformation $x=6X$ and $y=Y/6$ preserves the area of rectangles, so it preserves areas. The curve $xy=1$ is mapped to $XY=1$ and the trapezoid defining the area from $6$ to $12$ is mapped to the trapezoid defining the area from $1$ to $2$.

Comment: ^oughta be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
I = \int_{x=1}^{x=2} \frac{dx}{x}.
$$
Multiplying and dividing this expression by $6$, we have
$$
I = \int_{x=1}^{x=2} \frac{d(6x)}{6x}.
$$
Using the substitution $y=6x$, we have $dy=6dx$. When $x=1$, $y=6$, and when $x=2$, $y=12$. Therefore,
$$I = \int_{y=6}^{y=12} \frac{dy}{y}.$$